# Input is disabled by react but SCSS cannot read

Tags: reactjs, sass

In this React component, there is a checkbox that it is disabled if a condition is met.

The function of disabled of react is working correctly, but when the SCSS cannot apply the disabled properties because in the HTML it is not rendered the disabled attribute.

```
                  <fieldset>
                  <input className="form-check-input position-absolute ms-2 me-2 end-0" onClick={(e) => { e.stopPropagation(); elementsMap[e.id]?.length > 0 && toggleElement(e.id) }} checked={checkElement(e.id)}
                    disabled={elementsMap[e.id]?.length === 0}
                    type="checkbox" name={`element-${e.id}`}
                    id={`element-${element.id}`}
                  />
                  <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor={`element-${element.id}`} >
                    {e.name}<span className="ms-2 me-2 counter">({elementsMap[e.id]?.length || "0"})</span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
```

And here the SCSS code snippet

```
  .filter-dropdown{

    input:disabled {
      cursor: not-allowed;
    }
  
    input[disabled] + label{
        cursor: not-allowed;
        color: $primary;
        background-color: red;
    }

    input:disabled + label{
      cursor: not-allowed;
      color: $primary;
      background-color: red;
  }
```

An easy workaround will be to add a *.disabled* CSS class to the label, nevertheless I am just curious about what it is happening inside

Comment: If you're noticing the `disabled` attribute is not being applied to the input, are you sure the logic is applying it?
Using `disabled={elementsMap[e.id]?.length === 0}`, if `elementsMap[e.id]?.length === 0` is equating to `true` then It should be visible when inspecting the element in dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

I replied to my question if could it be helpful.

The problem was related to a piece of code where the condition was never true.

```
disabled={elementsMap[e.id]?.length === 0}
```

In this case, the element was null and obviously different than 0